# Sectioning UITableView Cells - Repeating Cells

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, tableview, indexpath

1. I'm trying to section my Tableview data based on a Key in my Firebase database.
2. I'm able to section everything properly based on the key (itemPreset).
3. I'm having trouble assigning the reusable cells to their sections.
4. The cells keep repeating themselves with the same text value in each cell.
5. The amount of rows per cell is correct and the section header title is correct.

Here is my code -

```
var subCategories = [SubCategoryCellInfo]()
var sectionsArray = [String]()

func querySections() -> [String] {
    for selection in subCategories {
        let subCategory = selection.itemPreset
        sectionsArray.append(subCategory ?? "")
    }
    let uniqueSectionsArray = Set(sectionsArray).sorted()
    return uniqueSectionsArray
}

func queryItemPreset(section:Int) -> [Int] {
    var sectionItems = [Int]()
    for selection in subCategories {
        let itemPreset = selection.itemPreset
        if itemPreset == querySections()[section] {
            sectionItems.append(querySections().count)
        }
    }
    return sectionItems
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return querySections().count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return querySections()[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isFiltering(){
        return filtered.count
    }
    return queryItemPreset(section: section).count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let subCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "subCell", for: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell
    let section = queryItemPreset(section: indexPath.section)

    let task = section[indexPath.row]
    let sub: SubCategoryCellInfo
    if isFiltering(){
        sub = filtered[task]
    }
    else{
        sub = subCategories[task]
    }
    subCell.nameOfLocationText.text = sub.itemPreset
    return subCell
}
```

SubCategoryCellInfo:

```
class SubCategoryCellInfo{
var itemPreset: String?

init(itemPreset:String?){
    self.itemPreset = itemPreset
}   
}
```

Solution:
I grouped the array into sections based on itemPreset and then used that section

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let subCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "subCell", for: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell
    let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: subCategories) { (person) -> String in
    return person.itemPreset ?? ""
    }

    var grouped = [[SubCategoryCellInfo]]()

    let keys = groupedDictionary.keys.sorted()

    keys.forEach { (key) in
        grouped.append(groupedDictionary[key]!)
    }

    let task = grouped[indexPath.section]

    let sub: SubCategoryCellInfo
    if isFiltering(){
        sub = filtered[indexPath.row]
    }
    else{
        sub = task[indexPath.row]
    }
    subCell.nameOfLocationText.text = sub.itemPreset
    return subCell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Group the array into sections based on itemPreset and then use that section.

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
let subCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "subCell", for: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell
let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: subCategories) { (person) -> String in
return person.itemPreset ?? ""
}

var grouped = [[SubCategoryCellInfo]]()

let keys = groupedDictionary.keys.sorted()

keys.forEach { (key) in
    grouped.append(groupedDictionary[key]!)
}

let task = grouped[indexPath.section]

let sub: SubCategoryCellInfo
if isFiltering(){
    sub = filtered[indexPath.row]
}
else{
    sub = task[indexPath.row]
}
subCell.nameOfLocationText.text = sub.itemPreset
return subCell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your **SubCategoryTableViewCell** write this code.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
     super.prepareForReuse()
     nameOfLocationText.text = nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. The cells still repeat themselves. If I do

        sub = subCategories[indexPath.row] it puts the cells into the correct row but not the correct section, and if I put sub = subCategories[indexPath.section] it puts the cells into the correct section but not the correct row.

Comment: Figured it out, added the solution to the main question.